# Regular Expression to get the String/StringBuffer value coming in multiple line

Tags: java, regex

Suppose we have a string like:

```
String str = "Some value" +
             "value 2" + variable + "value 3";
```

i want a multiLine regular expression that can give me the value of `str`.

For String i was using `"(.+)\\s*[+=]\\s*(.+)(.*)[\\+]"` but it fails for many possible declaration of String.

And also for StringBuffer like:

```
query.append("Some Value").append(" value 2")
     .append(variable).append(" value 3");
```

For this also multiline regular expression that can provide me value of `query`

For StringBuffer i was using `"[\\s]*([\\w]*)\\.append[\\s]*[(][\\s]*([\"][[^\"]|\"\"]*[\"])(.*)[)].*"`.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think you need to narrow down the problem for us.  Right now it looks like you're trying to use a regex as a replacement for a Java compiler.

Answer (score 0):

Use a `Pattern` and compile your regex with `Pattern.DOTALL`.

And BTW, in order to match a paren, you just need to use `\(` (ie, `"\\("` when quoted), no need for a character class.

Comment: All the MULTILINE option does is change the behavior of the anchors, `^` and `$`, causingg them to match at line boundaries as well as at the start/end of the input.  Maybe you're thinking of the DOTALL option, which allows the `.` metacharacter to match all characters *including* newlines.